# jQuery event listener fires before selector applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm stuck on some event listeners. When one element is clicked I want to create another listener for clicks. For some reason they are both firing. Here's the code and a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/uHIyiGi/2/edit
HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
 <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(event){
  $('body').append('<p>button clicked</p>');
  $('.wrap').addClass('clicked');

  $('body').on('click', '.clicked', function(e){
    $('body').append('<p>.clicked clicked</p>');
    $('.wrap').removeClass('clicked');
    $('body').off('click', '.clicked');
  });
});
```

From what I understand about event listeners, the second one should not fire until the '.clicked' element has a complete click event (a mouse down and mouse up), but it fires on the first click, meaning the event is fired even though the element doesn't have the trigger class until after the event. I'm seeing the event listener successfully removed each time, but it's called before I think it should be called. So, I'm really confused now... any suggestions? I'm hoping I have a face palm in my near future.

Comment: **[check this one](http://jsfiddle.net/MqbXu/1/)**. Are you looking into this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Events bubble. When you click on the button, you're adding an event to the body. Once the event handler for the button is complete (meaning, the wrap now has a clicked class), it then continues to bubble up the DOM until it reaches the body.  Since the body now has a new click event, said event also gets triggered. jQuery then looks within the body for an element matching the `.clicked` selector, calling the handler on any that it finds. To stop this, you can either delay binding the event to the body with a setTimeout, or stop Propagation on the button's click event so that it won't bubble up to the body.

```
$('button').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    ...
```

Timeline:

1. mousedown event is triggered, followed by a mouseup event both on the button
2. click event handler is triggered on button
3. `clicked` class is added to `.wrap` div
4. click event is bound to the body, delegated to elements matching `.clicked`
5. event bubbles up through the dom to the body
6. click event handler is triggered on the body
7. jQuery's click event handler looks for any elements that are descendants of the current element (the body) that match the `.clicked` selector
8. it finds the `.wrap` div that has a `clicked` class and calls the event handler on that element.

Comment: Right, I get that events bubble, but dpcumentation states: "The click event is only triggered after this exact series of events: The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the element. The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the element".

Comment: Why does the "nested" event fire if the selector class isn't present when the click initiates.

Comment: Right, but once that event is triggered, the event as a whole will bubble. By the time the event reaches the body, the wrap div will have a clicked class.

Comment: When the event reaches the body via bubbling, jQuery then looks for an element inside the body that matches the `.clicked` selector. Since the wrap now has that class, the handler will be triggered on the wrap.

Comment: @circlecube: It doesn't matter if the class was there or not on mousdown. The element is only inspected after the click, at which time it has the class.

Comment: ok that makes sense I guess. hadn't thought about the bubbling procedurally I guess. Thanks for explaining.