# jQuery event listener fires before selector applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, event-listener, event-bubbling

I am trying to make a system that would require an admin to click a delete button twice before it fires the action. if he focusout of the button, it resets.

```js
$(".unarmed").css("filter", "grayscale(1)").removeClass("armed").click(function(e) {
  $(this).css("filter", "").removeClass("unarmed").addClass("armed");
}).mouseout(function() {
  $(this).css("filter", "grayscale(1)").removeClass("armed").addClass("unarmed");
});

$("body").on("click", ".armed", function() {
  alert("boom");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="unwait unarmed" src="plus.png">
```

I've seen [jQuery event listener fires before selector applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18320535/jquery-event-listener-fires-before-selector-applied) but adding `e.stopPropagation()` causes the second click to not fire.

when `e.stopPropagation()` is not in the code, it does fire the second click, but together with the first click (i think this means the problem is not with the second click selector)

here is a fiddle with `e.stopPropagation()`:
https://jsfiddle.net/3jyr72t6/

also, if you have suggestion for making it prettier, i'm open for suggestions :D

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/drz2gk1j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@icecub answer as snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".unarmed").css("filter", "grayscale(1)");
  $(".unarmed").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("armed")) {
      console.log("boom");
    }
    $(this).css("filter", "").removeClass("unarmed").addClass("armed");
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("filter", "grayscale(1)").removeClass("armed").addClass("unarmed");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="unwait unarmed" src="https://kns.im/include/img/plus.png" style="width:50px">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always just use the jquery **dblclick** event. [Jquery dblclick](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

```js
$(document).on("dblclick",".btn-delete",function(){      
  console.log("DELETE");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-delete">DELETE</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this would be a solution, but I was aiming for a different UX. first the button is gray (unarmed). then when clicked once, it changes color (as in "armed"). Then, if it is clicked again, it fires. if user focuses out, it "disarms" and turns gray again.

maybe I'm over complicating things

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function to detect click outside the element .. See the next example

```js
$("img.unwait").on("click" , function(e){
  let $this = $(this);
  if($this.hasClass("unarmed")){
    $this.removeClass("unarmed").addClass("armed");
  }else if($this.hasClass("armed")){
    alert("BOOM");
    $this.removeClass("armed").addClass("unarmed");
  }
});
detect_click_out(".armed" , function(){
  $(".armed").removeClass("armed").addClass("unarmed");
});

function detect_click_out(element_selector , action){
  $(document).on('click',function(e){
    if (!$(element_selector).is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && $(element_selector).has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {action();} // run the action as a function
  });
}
```

```css
img{
  width : 50px;
}
.unarmed{
  filter : grayscale(1);
}
.armed{
  filter : grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="unwait unarmed" src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/sm/20180515/sm_5afb099d307d3.jpg">
```